# Comparison between textPersonName and textPassword

Tags: java, android, string, operators

My activity it's a simple login activity where (for tests only) it will return true if the username && password are equal and false if not.

But it always return false.

Not even if I convert `toString();` example:

```
String a=(txtUserName.getText().toString() == txtPassword.getText().toString()) ? "equal" : "Nequal";
```

Full code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
  txtUserName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
  txtPassword = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
  btnLogin = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
  btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override


      public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,txtUserName.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Just for separate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,txtPassword.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      String a=(txtUserName.getText() == txtPassword.getText()) ? "equal" : "Nequal";

      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

  });
}
```

Comment: You are comfusing ==, which compares pointers, with .equals() which compares contents.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
  String a=(txtUserName.getText().toString().equals(txtPassword.getText().toString()))
```

The way you are doing are not equating string rather they are equating string objects.
Always use String.equals() method for string comparison.

[Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: I've tried with the equals: if(txtUserName.getText().equals(txtPassword.getText())){
     
     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "equal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } else{
          
          
          Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Nequal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }  and the return it's the same "Nequal"

Comment: `String a=("xyz".equals("xyz"))? "equal" : "Nequal";` I tried this and working fine for me. make sure values your are getting are equal, if they are not then it will return `false`.

Comment: Thanks its solved with the equals and toString ;)

Answer (score 1):

To compare string values, use String's `equals` method; the `==` operator for object references compares for reference equality and since they are two different objects it will always return false.

```
txtUserName.getText().equals(txtPassword.getText())
```

Comment: Actually, there is some JRE magic for String where boxing may result in == returning true more often than might otherwise be expected.  The core answer is correct, though -- the poster should use .equals to compare contents.